# Can't conform to protocol using an existential in an associated value instead of a type erasure. Why?

Tags: swift, existential-type

The following code will throw an error - "Type 'SomeEnum' does not conform to protocol 'Equatable'" (and Hashable) - even though *SomeProtocol* conforms to Hashable and Equatable. Why?

One way to fix this is erasing the type to AnySomeProtocol, but I'm curious why is this a compiler error. I'd rather not erase the type when the existential seems to me the most expressive way to go about this.

```
import Foundation

enum SomeEnum: Hashable, Equatable {
    case foo
    case associatedFoo(any SomeProtocol)
}


protocol SomeProtocol: Hashable, Equatable {
    var field: String { get }
}

struct SomeDataType: Hashable, Equatable {
    let field: String
    let anotherField: Int
}

extension SomeDataType: SomeProtocol {}
```

Comment: An Orange can conform to SomeProtocol and an Apple can conform to SomeProtocol but can an Orange object be compared to an Apple object? These are two different types and even if both conforms to Equatable they can only be equal to objects of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Type erasure won't actually help. Adding to the question how you think it would, would probably rubber duckily answer the question for yourself.

You've got to have the associated types match, in order for them to be `Equatable`.

```swift
enum SomeEnum<AssociatedFoo: SomeProtocol>: Hashable {
  case foo
  case associatedFoo(AssociatedFoo)
}
```

---

You can implement this yourself, given the definition you provided instead, but it won't be synthesized in Swift 5.8 and there's been no talk of it changing that I know of.

```swift
extension SomeEnum: Equatable {
  static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
    switch (lhs, rhs) {
    case (.foo, .foo): return true
    case (.associatedFoo(let foo0), .associatedFoo(let foo1)): return foo0.equals(foo1)
    default: return false
    }
  }
}

public extension Equatable {
  /// Equate with a value of unknown type.
  func equals(_ any: some Any) -> Bool {
    self == any as? Self
  }
}
```

```swift
extension SomeEnum: Hashable {
  func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    switch self {
    case .foo:
      hasher.combine(0)
    case .associatedFoo(let foo):
      hasher.combine(1)
      hasher.combine(foo)
    }
  }
}
```